# How can Fix this error ? 'Corpus' is not defined

Tags: python

I tried this but an error came up saying corpus is not defined

import pandas as pd

```
import os
import csv
import nltk
import nltk.corpus
from nltk import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk.corpus
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect=CountVectorizer()

import nltk
token_list=[]
for sentence in Corpus:
    token_list.append(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))

print(token_list[0])
print(token_list[1])
```

And this error came up how can I fix this?

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-de7f807821cb> in <module>
      1 import nltk
      2 token_list=[]
----> 3 for sentence in Corpus:
      4     token_list.append(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
      5 

NameError: name 'Corpus' is not defined
```

Comment: What do want to do? What is the input? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Why did you import it twice? `import nltk.corpus`?

Answer (score 4):

You import `nltk.corpus`, not `corpus`. Hence you have to use `nltk.corpus` everywhere in your code. The common way to use `corpus` directly is

```
from nltk import corpus
```

Note this is a lowercase word. If you really wanted it to be uppercase:

```
import nltk.corpus as Corpus
```

Comment: I corrected it as from nltk import corpus but this error happened

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-4a6cab561055> in <module>
      1 import nltk
      2 token_list=[]
----> 3 for sentence in corpus:
      4     token_list.append(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
      5 

TypeError: 'LazyModule' object is not iterable

Comment: @N.Perera Looks like a good topic for a new question. SO is a question and answer site, it's bad form to change the question after the fact. If this solved your original problem accept the answer. If you have another question feel free to ask it. Also you might want to have a look at [ask]. As a quick answer that's because you are probably not using what you want to, but to elaborate would require more room - hence, a new question. You can also read https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.html to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You try changing Corpus -> nltk.corpus

```
for sentence in nltk.corpus:
```

if you just 'import' not 'from module import *', the module name must be prefixed in python.